# PHP Increment/Decrement value from xml

Tags: php, xml, increment, decrement

This is my xml.

```
    <episodes>
        <episode>
           <series_name>Test</series_name>
            <season_number>1</season_number>
            <episode_number>10</episode_number>
            <episodes_in_season>12</episodes_in_season>
            <notes>Testing</notes>
         </episode>
    </episodes>
```

What i want to do is get the number of season/episode number and increment or decrement i from that xml and then save it back (i have +/- buttons on my page for season_number and for episode_number, and i am using `$_post for that button).

And here is my code so far.

```
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load($user);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($xmlDoc);
$test = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('episode')->item(0);

// example for episode number increment / decrement (what i think)

   $number = $test->childNodes->item(2); 

    $increment = $number + 1; 
    $decrement = $number - 1; // example
```

i am stuck here and i didn't complete it since i can't see whats going on in `$number` because i am getting this error **Object of class DOMElement could not be converted to int.**

i have also tried it with  `(int)$number = $test->childNodes->item(2);` but with no luck. And also i am a beginner in php so i might got this thing wrong all together.

**edit:**

```
  $eNumber = $xpath->query('episode_number', 'episode')->item(0);
      $esNumber = $xpath->query('episodes_in_season', 'episode')->item(0);
     if ($eNumber == $esNumber)
     {
        echo "You have reached the max episode in season";

     }
     else
     {

     $eNumber->nodeValue++;
     }
```

it always says i have reached the max episode

Comment: Tried this $number = (int)$test->childNodes->item(2) too?

Comment: I think you posted the wrong XML. You search for tags named 'series' but your example only has 'episode'.

Comment: @fab Yeah i forgot to change that here, did it now. Ty

Comment: No need to, see comment below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$number` is the `DOMElement` corresponding to episode_number, do the following to increment:

```
$number->nodeValue++;
```

By the way, instead of `$number = $test->childNodes->item(2);` I would recommend XPath to always address the correct element:

```
$number = $xpath->query('episode_number', $test)->item(0);
```

Comment: Will try that.. will get back to you fab.

Comment: Worked like a charm :) ty. Edit: ok will try that also

Answer (score 2):

The [DOMNodelist::item()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnodelist.item.php) method you are using does not return a value (neither string nor integer), it returns a node:

> `DOMNode DOMNodelist::item ( int $index )`

As such (and assuming your Xpath query was correct), you need to access its [nodeValue](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.nodevalue) property to read the number. Then, if you cast to integer make sure you do it *before* you assign the result to a variable:

```
$number = (int)$test->childNodes->item(2)->nodeValue;
```

... though it's normally not necessary since PHP will do it for you as soon as you do math:

```
$foo = '33';
var_dump($foo); // string(2) "33"
$foo++;
var_dump($foo); // int(34)
```

Comment: This does not work. You cannot convert DOMElement objects to int or string, neither implicitly (like in the question) nor explicitly (like in your answer).

Comment: Probably you were thinking of `SimpleXMLElement` ;-)

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario np tried like fab said and it worked, anyway thank you both.

Comment: @fab - You bet I was! Although the question has been answered, I've fixed my answer for the records.

Comment: Mind if ask you one more thing... don't want to open another question as it is in topic with this one

Comment: @fab and ÁlvaroG.Vicario Mind if ask you one more thing... don't want to open another question as it is in topic with this one (see edit)

Comment: @MePo - Please read answers carefully. `item(0)` returns an object, you want `item(0)->nodeValue` every time you need the number. Additionally, learn to use `var_dump()`.

Comment: ok got it and ty again.. and sorry for troubling you. will do that